# Why is my keyboard acting like the Ctrl key is pressed when I hit an F key?

Tags: windows, keyboard

So, [I'm gradually getting the hang of the Kinesis Advantage Pro keyboard](http://philosopherdeveloper.wordpress.com/2011/01/02/guess-what-im-doing-right-now-a-k-a-another-random-post/) that my wife bought me for Christmas. I love it so far. But something very strange happened today. (Note: I actually have no idea if this problem has anything to do with the Kinesis keyboard per se. All I know is that I never encountered this problem until after replacing my old keyboard with the Kinesis.)

It seems that **if I press an F key (e.g., <kbd>F2</kbd>), the computer starts acting like I'm holding down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key**. For example if I click on a link in my web browser, it now opens in a new tab. Or if I hit <kbd>A</kbd> all the text in the document I'm editing gets selected. This behavior persists until I manually hit the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key again.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? What could cause such behavior?

Comment: Oh my HEAVENS that is an ugly keyboard.  I hope it helps with your RSI.  (I hope you have RSI because oh my HEAVENS that is an ugly keyboard.)

Comment: @Shinrai: You hope I have RSI? That's pretty messed up!

Comment: ohmygodi'msosorry D: But uh what I mean is that I can't think of any other excuse to use that.  It's like diabetic footwear or something. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, turns out I just needed to read the manual.

The Kinesis Advantage Pro has macros that are accessed via the F keys. I don't know if some came pre-installed on my keyboard, or if I accidentally defined some myself. In any case, the solution was to clear my keyboard's memory by holding down <kbd>Progrm</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> and waiting for the lights on the board to stop flashing. That did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I have run into 2 extremely similar problems which roughly fit this description. After a year of living with them, I finally figured out how to fix them.

(1) Press Ctrl-Shift a few times. This seems to fix it for me. When I hit ctrl-c, it no longer puts the cents symbol. Pressing ctrl alone and shift alone may not be sufficient to fix this.

This problem, bafflingly, is always specific to the application/window. Quitting and restarting each app fixes it for that app. I have this problem both with the Advantage2 Kinesis and Advantage Kinesys. It seems to be specific to my work machine and never my home machine. Oddly, it happens even when I remote desktop in from home to work. It may be Windows 7 specific. I read about a Advantage1-Windows7 problem which is fixed by either a bios change (disable usb 3 or turn on usb debug mode), a usb-to-ps2 dongle (plug usb keyboard into ps2 port) or an Advantage2 but I think this is a different problem because my Advantage2 (LF) has the same problem.

(2) Press Alt-Shift once. This is the default hotkey to switch keyboard input languages in Windows. See the control panel. Every once in a while, I accidentally hit alt-shift as I type a hotkey and trigger this. When I hit shift-3, it no longer puts "/". If you disable all the alternate keyboard layouts, this problem goes away.